# Is there any word for discount on next bought item(s)?

Tags: word-request

How to say in English (is there single word) for selling program: you buy an item and then you can have some discount on next one (the same or of another kind)?

Comment: "Buy One Get Two"; ["Buy One Get One Free"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buy_one,_get_one_free); "Buy One Get One".

Comment: If it's a discount rather than getting one free, something like "Buy one get one half price" would apply.

Comment: @Student, thanks! Nice! What about discount?)

Comment: I don't know a word for this in general. It is the principle of most "loyalty card" schemes.

Comment: [Three for the price of two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buy_one,_get_one_free)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single word you may be looking for might either be **sale** or **promotion**.

When a product is on **sale** it is usually sold at a discounted price to the regular price.

When a product has a **promotion** it will usually have offers of multiple buys at a discounted price or some connection with other products in the same promotion.

In BrE when a product is on sale or being promoted it is referred to as begin **on offer**.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in the comments, usually the name of the sale is a shortened form of the terms of the promotion, like "Buy one, get one" or "Buy one, get one half off". Sometimes "Buy one, get one" is referred to as a BOGO sale and "Buy one, get one half off" is BOGOHO because they are both well-known types of promotions.

Another example is a "[one cent sale](http://pittsburgh.cbslocal.com/2016/02/26/jcpenney-announces-one-cent-sale/)" where if you meet some requirements, you may buy something for a penny. There are additional terms, for example, not everything in the store is eligible to be bought with a penny, but most people understand that even thought the description doesn't explain that.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, the 'buy one get one free' offer is sometimes abbreviated to BOGOF. Us Brits find this amusing, because it sounds like 'bog off', a rather rude way to tell someone to go away.

Supermarkets will often refer to these kind of discounts as 'multibuy' offers.